# C# DataGridView : override keydown events

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, overriding

i am working with DataGridView trying to provide specific utility to my user...

what i want to do is when some key is presses instead of the normal function that the key was supposed to perform like updown arrows and page up down keys etc i want to stop the default action

like when on a selected row, datagrid in `selectfullrow`, when down arrow is press it shouldn't change the row selection or goto the next row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should handle the KeyDown event and set the e.Handled to true to disable the default action:

```
    private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        e.Handled = e.KeyCode == Keys.Down;
    }
```